# Android : Button Error. Visible in Marshmallow Not seen in Kitkat AVD?

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an Android Application for Music Player. Here In my tabbed layout i have placed a Botton. While running my project the Button is shown in Marshmallow AVD . But while I running the same programme on KITKAT AVD the button is not seen ..
Can any one help me to find the error ..?

My Xml Code,......

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Millenium   Audios" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >



        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="403dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="clikplayer"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />
        </FrameLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
            />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the button on the bottom of the screen?Because I have tested your provide layout in kitkat and also in gellybean and I can see the button in both.

Comment: Yes the same...  but i;m having the problem .. Let me try again